gtk scrollbar arrow sensitivity -- can I change it?
Following various ideas on the internet I did manage to modify my scrollbars by making various setting in file:
/root/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
... but one thing I haven't figured out how to do is make the up and down arrows scroll faster -- they are glacially slow.  This doesn't work:
scrollbar
{
    -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: true;   < works
    -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: true;    < works
    background-color: #cccccc;                  < works
    -GtkRange-upper-stepper-sensitivity: 100;   < does not work
}

... anything I can do?  In the best of all possible worlds perhaps the arrows might do a 'page up' in the terminal.


In the best of all possible worlds perhaps the arrows might do a 'page up' in the terminal.

Stepper arrows scroll line-by-line in practically all toolkits that have stepper arrows. To scroll by ~whole page, click the area above or below the scroll slider – middle-click in GTK, left-click in Qt/Windows/Motif. (I don't know why GTK decided to swap left and middle.)

Tx.  I'll take it that there's no way.  Yeah, I know the other ways of paging.  I think I'll just remove the arrows then.  I'd hoped there might be some way of just speeding things up, like maybe 10X as fast.  You'd think that with all the functionality that is there, that faster scrolling might also be available.
